# Как получить ссылку на правку?

Tags: поддержка, предлагаемые-правки

Вот попался мне вопрос или ответ с ожидающей правкой. Но не в очереди, а просто попался.

Если я отклоняю эту правку (т. е. принятой она не станет, ну или пока не стала), то как мне прямо сейчас получить на неё ссылку?

Comment: Так из браузера же ссылку и взять. Не? Или в [истории](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history).

Comment: @alexolut, "Но не в очереди". В браузере её тоже нет - это же в попапе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ссылка на предлагаемую правку присутствует непосредственно на ссылке `править` под вопросом. Пример:

> [image: правка]

Если ссылку открыть в новой вкладке, а не просто кликом, то она отобразится так же как и в очереди проверок, а не pop-up окном.